# Images on aws amplify

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, next.js

I create a web app using next.js and react. When i deploy on vercel everything runs smoothly, but when i try to do it on aws amplify the images doesn't show. Does anybody know why?

I tried using cloudinary instead of local images. The odd thing is, i'm using firebase as storage for my posts and testimonials, and those images show. But when is locally or from a url, it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

I have a nextjs site hosted on Amplify and I had the same problem, for local images to work I added this to my `next.config.js` :

```
images: {
    loader: 'akamai',
    path: '/'
}
```

sample final code:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  distDir: 'build',
  images: {
    loader: 'akamai',
    path: '/'
  }
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

Remember to use the `<Image />` of next.

Example:

```
<Link href="#">
  <a>
    <Image
      className={styles.photo}
      src="/images/photo.png"
      alt="Logo"
      width={46}
      height={46}
    />
  </a>
</Link>
```